# Differentiate Hex value among string (char array) in C

Tags: c

I am parsing an XML in C, and the server that returns me the response XML is introducing some hexadecimal values (in alphanumeric format) in between the actual XML. Since I parsing this in C, as char array, I am not able to differentiate between actual string of XML and the hex value, being (0-9, a-e and A-E). So is there any way I can identify these hex value?

Note - `isxdigit()` didn't help, as it compares the character with actual characters of 0-9 a-e and A-E.

Example of String - `<a:Manufacturer>Apple</a:Manufacturer><a:Materiafe8lStandardName i:nil="true"/><a:Model>iPhone 7 Plus 256GB Silver - ATT</a:Model>`

"fe8" is the hex value breaking "MaterialStandardName"

Comment: Even human won't be able to "differentiate" that. Because there is no difference. Is "dead" a hex string or a word?

Comment: Seriously? How do you expect to tell the different between `f` and `f`? Can you tell me which of those is the hex, and which is the letter? (hint: you will get it wrong)

Comment: Hmmm, maybe it is "afe8" is the hex value breaking "MaterilStandardName"`?

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be a classic [xy-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). The problem is there is "garbage" in your content. But your attempted solution is futile. As you show the content, it is just broken XML.

Nevertheless, I have a strong guess about the actual problem: You receive this data from a http server and this server sends it using [Transfer-Encoding: chunked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding). The `fe8` is inserted as the size of the next chunk sent over the wire.

So instead of trying to somehow fix your garbled content, look at where you receive it and fix the transport layer to handle the server response correctly and only return actual payload.

Comment: Good catch on the chunked encoding thing.

Comment: Yes, the encoding is "Chunked" so the hex value introduced is defining the further expected size of characters or chunk. Got the idea, Thanks for the help.